# Zoom window is too small on Ubuntu 20.04 with a 4K screen resolution and 200% scaling

Tags: display, display-resolution, scaling

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a 4K screen with 200% scaling, and when I run Zoom, the menus and texts are simply too small. All other applications are scaling as expected.

I've attached an print screen with Zoom open, and with the terminal output.

Does anyone knows how to work around this while retaining the 4K res?

[Terminal output when running zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11kwc.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you just press the maximize button?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha maximizing the window doesn't change the scale of the texts. It continues to be hard to read

Comment: Modify the zoom config file in .config/zoomus.conf https://superuser.com/questions/1381054/how-to-enable-hidpi-support-on-zoom-us-linux-client

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @blupp there are some solutions now

Answer (score 14):

Zoom currently creates a file named `zoomus.conf` under your `.config` folder in the user's home folder.

One of the settings is `ScaleFactor`, set to 1 by default. Set this to 2, and next time you start the application it will have appropriate-sized visuals.

Comment: This is good except it makes the cursor absolutely huge.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, it helped to go to `.config/zoomus.conf` and set

```
autoScale=true
```

Comment: This worked for me, best answer.

Comment: worked for me—btw future readers, when I tried doing both `scaleFactor=1` and `autoScale=true` it ended up 2× haha

Comment: @MalcolmOcean do you know what should be the value of the `autoScale` parameter for not letting everything become 2x? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure what I meant. It looks like I have `autoScale=true` and `scaleFactor=1` set now and it behaves correctly. Try stuff and report back!

Comment: Simply setting `autoScale=false` fixed my issue.

Comment: fractional scale factor is allowed
autoScale=true
scaleFactor=1.5

Answer (score -1):

This was due to Display Scaling in my case.

Go to Screen Display in settings and choose **Scale** to 100% (if you see 200%) and change the **Resolution** to a lower value. In my case, I had to bring it down from `3840 x 2400 (16:10)` to `1920 x 1200 (16:10)`.

[image]